# Git reset in detached HEAD state

Tags: git, git-reset

I understand that the `git reset` command moves a branch backwards in the history (*), and that the branch it moves is the one that `HEAD` is pointing to.

So I got curious and I tried to call it in a `detached HEAD state` to see what would happen. I was expecting error but git did something, and I'm just unable to figure out what it did.

Did Git acted like `HEAD` was still pointing to where it was before I checked out and went into the `detached HEAD state` ?

---

**[ Edit 1 ]** I actually figured it out. It does exactly the same as when one is not in a detached head state, except that it doesnt move any branch backward. It's only the

**[ Edit 2(*) ]** The `git reset` actually only moves a branch backward in history when specifying an older commit. When doing `git reset HEAD`, it leaves the branch where it is (see comments below).

Comment: You should update your question with the exact command you've run... There are three forms of git reset... Each with parameters.. most common use performs the oposite operation of git add...

Comment: I' not sure it matters here. Since every version of git reset does at least one thing : it moves the current branch to a different location. And since there are not really a current branch in a detached head, i'm wondering what happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git reset` makes the current branch and HEAD move to a specific commit. If it's a detached HEAD, it makes only HEAD move.

Comment: Indeed, i just checked, only HEAD moves. But then git tells me that I have unstaged files and thats what i'm wondering. What files are those ? Are they the ones from the top commit I detached head from, or the ones that I just checked out (the ones that were staged at the time I did this commit)

Comment: @Radioreve `git reset` has some options like `--soft`, `--mixed`, `--hard`. `--mixed` is the default.  Suppose the commit history is `A-B-C`. If `git reset B`, equal to `git reset B --mixed`, HEAD moves to B but the changes from B to C are kept as unstaged. If `git reset B --soft`, the changes are kept as uncommitted. If `git reset B --hard`, the changes are discarded. After `git reset`, run `git status` to check.

Answer (score 4):

Just to stress:

> I understand that the git reset command always moves a branch backwards in the history,

This is not correct and you might want to edit your question to avoid confusing people new to git. For example, `git reset --hard` does not do that, it just wipes out the working directory and the index without moving HEAD or the branch.

In fact, all variants where you omit the optional `<commit>` in `git reset [<commit>]` do not move the head nor the branch. Other options of `git reset` do other things, not all of which move HEAD. So moving HEAD around is just one of several actions `git reset`can do.

Comment: Conceptually, `git reset` *does* always move `HEAD`, it's just that if you move from where you're standing now, to where you're standing now, that move is so small and so fast :-) that nobody can see you move and they refuse to believe that you moved. :-) However, you're definitely correct that it does not have to move backwards: it can move to where it is now (the non-moving "move"), or move forwards, or move sideways ("jumping tracks" to an unrelated commit).

Answer (score -1):

If you've run just: `git reset`

It performs the opposite operation of `git add` which is unstage changes...

There are three forms of the `git reset` command, each one with associated options and performing different operations. Check on [git reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) docs if you want to go deeper.